# SQl Server 2012 autofill one column from another

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a table where a user inputs name, dob, etc. and I have a User_Name column that I want automatically populated from other columns.

For example input is: Name - John Doe, DOB - 01/01/1900

I want the `User_Name` column to be automatically populated with `johndoe01011900` (I already have the algorithm to concatenate the column parts to achieve the desired result)

I just need to know how (SQL, Trigger) to have the `User_Name` column filled once the user completes imputing ALL target columns. What if the user skips around and does not input the data in order? Of course the columns that are needed are (not null).

Comment: What happens if they edit their name subsequently? Should that cascade to the UserName so they get a new user name? Should the columns always be in synch?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

you can use a calculated field with the following calculation:

```
LOWER(REPLACE(Name, ' ', ''))+CONVERT(   VARCHAR(10), DateOfBirth, 112))
```

In the below sample I have used a temp table but this is the same for regular tables as well.

SAMPLE:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(Name        VARCHAR(100)
              , DateOfBirth DATE
              , CalcField AS LOWER(REPLACE(Name, ' ', ''))+CONVERT(   VARCHAR(10), DateOfBirth, 112));

INSERT INTO      #temp(Name
                 , DateOfBirth)
VALUES
      ('John Doe'
     , '01/01/1900');

SELECT *
FROM   #temp;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: So if a user in inserting a new record after he put in all required fields it will fill in the field for him?  How about if an existing record is updated (women sometimes take the husband's last name) will the calculated field update?

Comment: BTW the users will be imputing data to a permanent production table via a local app (Excel or Access) on their PC via ODBC linked table.  I don't want the local app to calculate the field since there may be numerous apps and changing the way the field is calculated is easier if there is only 1 point of